# Express Validator: How can validate email as well username in same field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I'm building an app on express (nodejs framework), where I'd like to allow a user to login by providing either email address or username. So my question is, how can we implement validation for two different types of input on same field in express-validator.

To validate email address, I had written validator code like below.

```
check('email')
    .trim()
    .escape()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('Please enter Email Address.')
    .bail()
    .normalizeEmail()
    .isEmail()
    .withMessage('Please enter valid Email Address.')
    .bail(),
```

So basically, I want this code, to check for both cases (email or username).

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you expect if i use my email as username? Do you really need two validations?

Answer (score 0):

Just npm install @hapi/joi it's the most used input validator. Solves all that elegantly.